# Count words in DOM string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML string:

```
<div><p>Hello <b>how are</b> you?</div>
```

I would like to loop the HTML string DOM and wrap each word with a span tag and the word number as id so result will be like this:

```
<div><p><span id="word-1">Hello</span> <b><span id="word-2">how</span> <span id="word-3">are</span></b> <span id="word-4">you?</span></div>
```

I've tried to use the JQuery method `$.parseHTML` but no luck to count the words because DOM node value can contain more than one word in it..

In addition, if inside the word there is inline tags such `<b>` / `<i>` so from DOM point of view each tag has a different node value even when its the same word)

Any idea how to solve this issue? how to count words inside a HTML DOM string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <div><p>Hello <b>how are</b> you?</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var textNodes = $("#content *").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});

var counter = 1;
for(var i = 0;i<textNodes.length;i++)
{
    var val = $(textNodes).eq(i).text();
  var words = val.split(" ");
  var final = "";

  for(var j = 0;j<words.length;j++)
  {
    if(words[j].trim() != "")
    {
        final += "<span id='"+ counter +"'>"+ words[j] +" </span>";
      counter++;
    }
  }

  $($(textNodes)[i]).replaceWith(final);
}
```

[**Jsfiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/0gvufej4/13/)

Comment: Thanks but it will not work on words that contain inline tags such `<b>` for example: <div id="content"><p>He<i>ll</i>o <b>how are</b> you?</p></div> (it will divide the word hello into several words)

Comment: @user2678018 so if "He<i>ll</i>o" is found you want to consider it as a single word ?

Comment: Yes.. because most editors will render it as one word (with 2 letters bold)

Comment: Hard problem.. I'm trying to play with it.. but nothing working.. have you found some direction?

Comment: @user2678018 Its hard to assume a word like that. Nah. piratically no one will give b/i/u tags to few character of words. user will apply to whole word.

Comment: Is there a way to find those weird words and remove those inline tags from them before counting?

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding of your question this should work.

```
var allText = $("body").text().replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
var words = allText.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
  $(div).append("<span id = 'word-'"+i+">"+words[i]+"</span>")
}
```

Comment: Improper solution, You are removing tags here.